# How to get Apache Tika (as Maven Dependency) runnning in Java for a first Test using Eclipse?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, Maven, Tika, Eclipse. I want to try Tika. As far as I can see I have made it to set up Tika as a Maven dependency. I added this to my projects pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I used the following code from [https://tika.apache.org/1.16/examples.html]

```
public String parseToStringExample() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    try (InputStream stream = ParsingExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt")) {
        return tika.parseToString(stream);
    }
}
```

I think I imported all needed libraries. Eclipse still shows me 2 Errors in the line:

```
ParsingExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"))
```

The Errors:

1. Parsing Example cannot be resolved to a type
2. Resource Specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

Where does "ParsingExample" come from or by what should it be replaced?

In the context of Java syntax - what does the ".class" mean, behind "ParsingExample"? Is it something like a implicit defined class? Where does ".class" come from?

Is it really necessary to change the source level to 1.7 - why?

The file test.txt has to be in the same directory as the java file where this code lives, right?!

What else do I have to consider to make these lines of code running?

Sorry, that there are so many questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh dear. New to everything, you're going to have a hard time with this (if you even manage to get it working). However, the default source/target is `1.5`, so you need to [change that](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to solve one of your many problems.

Comment: What happens [if you take the full Parsing Example class, not just the method snippet](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ParsingExample.java) ?

Comment: Thank you all. I think I solved the problem on my own by having a look on some other example code. It's not necessary to play with the source/target version. I just used 1.8 - works. Also I have a way better understanding of how to interpret this snippet example.
@Kayaman I think your entire comment led me in the wrong direction, sorry.

Comment: @Gagravarr Oh yes, that would had helped me before, really. Man, I did not know this source - only the snippet. The bigger picture brought by you would had clarified a lot. I would vote it up as solution. But now it's still quite useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer. All of the [code examples on the Apache Tika website](https://tika.apache.org/1.16/examples.html) are pulled from [here in the Tika source tree](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/)

Specifically, the parsing example [comes from this complete example file](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ParsingExample.java)

The reference to `ParsingExample.class` is a reference to the example class itself that the method you're copying is taken from. You should either replace that with the name of your own class, or replace the whole line with your own preferred way of getting your input file into Tika